# Defining users within partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I am new to ruby on rails, and know this is a beginner error.  I'm trying to create an application that displays user comments within a post.  I have a comment partial pointing to my post#show, and when requesting to display <%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.small.url, class: "media-object") if comment.user.avatar? %> from _comment.html.erb, I get "undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass.  I've read other questions on stackoverflow  and I know this is saying it can't find a user associated with the post within comments and that I need to define user in my controller.  I'm assuming it's for the post controller, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the specific syntax to display comments by user in post.

```
#comments_controller
def create
 @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
 @comment.post = @post
 @comment.save
 authorize @comment
 redirect_to [@topic, @post]
end

#posts_controller
def show
 @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
 @post = Post.find(params[:id]) 
end

#post model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :topic
 has_one :summary
 has_many :comments
 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

#comment model
 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

#rendering comment partial in post#show
 <h1><%= @post.markdown_title %></h1>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <small>
    <%= image_tag(@post.image.thumb.url) if @post.image? %></br>
    <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
  submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by
   <%= @post.user.name %>
  </small>
  <p><%= @post.markdown_body %></p>
 </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
 <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %> 
<% end %>
<% if policy(@post).destroy? %>
  <%= link_to "Delete Post", [@topic, @post], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this post?" }  %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
 <% if policy(Comment.new).create? %>
   <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment } %>
   <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: {topic: @topic, post: @post} %>
<% else %>
  <h3>Sign up to Bloccit to post comments</h3>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %></br></br>
<% end %>
```

```
#comment partial
 <ul>
 <% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
  <div class="media">
   <div class="media-left">
    <%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.small.url, class: "media-object") if comment.user.avatar? %>
   </div>
   <div class="media-body">
    <small>
     <%= comment.user.name %> commented <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
  <% if policy(comment).destroy? %>
    | <%= link_to "Delete", [@topic, @post, comment], method: :delete %>
   <% end %>
   </small>
 <li>
  <p><%= c.body %></p>
</li>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Also, when I put @post.user = @user in posts_controller the error changes to "undefined method 'avatar' for nil:NilClass. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your `show.html.erb`?

Comment: @Mezbah, still throws the same error.

Comment: @Pavan, the post show.html.erb is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass

The error is because of this line

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment } %>
```

You don't have `@comment` initialized in `show` method of `posts_controller` and you are passing it as `locals` for `comment`, so `comment.user` returns error.

And also I've noticed that in `_comment.html.erb` you have this line `<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>`, so you can use `c` instead of `comment`.

```
<%= image_tag(c.user.avatar.small.url, class: "media-object") if c.user.avatar? %>
```

Comment: not having the @comment initialized in show method of posts_controller is now throwing additional errors.

Comment: There were a few errors, one of them was more of a flow issues — deleting an entire post instead of a single comment, or mentioning no method found for comment ids.  I fixed this by adding '@comment = post.comments' in my post_controller and adding '{ post: @post }' in my post#show view.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly referencing the block variable. Either change `|c|` to `|comment|` or change the `comment` references to `c`.

So like this:

```
<%= image_tag(c.user.avatar.small.url, class: "media-object") if c.user.avatar? %>
```